# some ways of parsing doc type and pdf type file

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing

I am creating an app in which i need to parse the documents uploaded by people, they can upload document either of the two types i.e. doc type or pdf type i want to know what are the various methods available to do that and which one is the best among them. iam creating the app in asp.net with c#

Comment: You are asking for a world of hurt, unless you buy something pre-made.

Comment: actually i am creating a resume parser

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [Aspose.NET](http://www.aspose.com/).  I've used it in the past and it's fairly powerful. It allows you to read/create/modify Word, Excel, PDFs and probably a few more.

As @John says, "You are asking for a world of hurt, unless you buy something pre-made."